# Parallel solutions of system $\vec{x}\,'=A(t)\vec{x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ are solutions of $\vec{x}\,'=A(t)\vec{x}$, with $A(t) \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})^{n \times n}$, show that if $\vec{x}_1(0)$ and $\vec{x}_2(0)$ are parallel, then $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ are parallel $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you write the solution of that system?

Comment: What does it mean for two points to be parallel?

Comment: Maybe that $\boldsymbol{x}_{1}\left(t\right)=\alpha\boldsymbol{x}_{2}\left(t\right)$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @eranreches: Who knows :-).

Comment: yes, mean $\vec{x}_1(t)=\alpha\vec{x}_2(t)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Also mean $\vec{x}_1(t) \times \vec{x}_2(t)=0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Surely linearity of solution applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions of $x'(t) = A(t)x(t)$ (where we suppose $A$ continuous) such that $x_2(0) = \alpha x_1(0)$, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.

Notice that by linearity, since $x_1$ is a solution of $x'(t) = A(t)x(t)$, $\alpha x_1$ is also a solution of $x'(t) = A(t)x(t)$.

By Picard-Lindelöf theorem, $\alpha x_1$ is the unique solution to the initial value problem $x'(t) = A(t)x(t), x(0) = \alpha x_1(0)$.

Since $\alpha x_1(0) = x_2(0)$, $\alpha x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions to the above initial value problem, so we have $\alpha x_1 = x_2$ by unicity of solutions.